# Regex for last capital letter in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression implemented in javascript that checks for all capital letters in a string:

`.match(/[A-Z]+[^A-Z]*|[^A-Z]+/g)`

then adds a space by `.join(" ")`

–

How can I write a regular expression that finds only the last capital letter instead, then joins a space before that letter? Thanks for your help.

—

Sample Input: "HelloMyNameIsNick"

Ideal Output: "HelloMyNameIs Nick"

Comment: Can you add sample input and expected output in question

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, I added that above. Do you have ideas that might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

```
'HelloMyNameIsNick'.replace(/([^ \n])([A-Z][^A-Z]*$)/gm, '$1 $2')
```

Test cases:

```js
console.log(`
HelloMyNameIsNick
Hello
 Hello
HELLO
HellO
HeLLo
Hello Test
HELLO TEST
hello test
HELLO 1$@(-.aa
HELLO 1$@(-.Aa
`.replace(/([^ \n])([A-Z][^A-Z]*$)/gm, '$1 $2'))
```

Check out test cases which are handled properly:

```
Hello
 Hello 
Hello Test
```

---

### Old answer that **only finds** last uppercase

What you are looking for is

```
/[A-Z](?!.*[A-Z].*)/gm
```

[Playground with tests](https://regex101.com/r/2iZDJ8/1)

It finds only the last capital letter.

If you want to find last letter in whole text instead on each line you can replace m (multiline) to s (single line):

```
/[A-Z](?!.*[A-Z].*)/gs
```

[Playground with tests](https://regex101.com/r/ukzyRg/1)

*Note `/ /s` flag may not be supported in all browsers.

`(?!ABC)` refers to negative lookahead. It checks conditions in expression but not includes them in the final result. [More info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 1):

To add a space before the last uppercase letter, greedily match *all* followed by a single uppercase letter:

```
"ABCabcABC".replace(/(.*)([A-Z])/, "$1 $2")
"ABCabcAB C"
```

To add a space before the last uppercase letter for each uppercase sequence, match an uppercase letter that is not followed by another uppercase letter:

```
"ABCabcAB".replaceAll(/([A-Z](?![A-Z]))/g, " $1")
"AB CabcA B"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a non-greedy quantifier:

```
/[A-Za-z]*?([A-Z])[^A-Z]*/
```

I suggest you add beginning and end anchors to make sure that you are matching the entire string, otherwise the pattern will segment strings:

```
/^[A-Za-z]*?([A-Z])[^A-Z]*$/
```

Try it out here: https://regex101.com/r/h9Acm6/1

Comment: Shouldn't it be greedy? This will find the first capital after the first letter.

Comment: This doesn't work :/ Thanks for the idea, though.

Comment: @NickB Apologies, could you try it out now?

Comment: @Barmar my thinking is to use a non-greedy pattern to consume as many letters (capital or otherwise) as possible, making sure to leave enough for the rest of the pattern (which matches a single capital letter).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... If you try it in the link above you should see that the capture group contains only the last capital letter in the string. Perhaps you can post a test case to help me understand what isn't working.

Comment: My mistake @zr0gravity7, I added more context above. I'm not sure why but your solution adds / returns the last capital letter into the output.

Comment: It's the `[^A-Z]*$` at the end that forces it to find the last capital letter. You don't even need `[A-Za-z]*?` before it.

Answer (score 0):

`.*([A-Z])[^A-Z]*`

[image]

Do recommend: https://regex101.com/

Comment: You don't need `.*` at the beginning. A regexp can match anywhere in the string.

Comment: And `{1}` is redundant -- everything matches 1 time unless it's quantified.

Comment: In fact we need `.*` at beggining if we do want only one match and group (and skip other uppercased letters). However I agree - `{1}` is totally redundant. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: I confused your answer with @zr0gravity7 which anchors at the end with `$`. The anchor makes `.*` unnecessary, since it forces matching the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of lookahead to assert your position right before the final capital letter.

```js
console.log("HelloMyNameIsNick".replace(/(?=[A-Z][^A-Z]*$)/, ' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to match an uppercase char, and then match any char except an uppercase char till the end of the string.

Replace with a space and the full match.

```
[A-Z][^A-Z\n]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZOTROg/1)

```js
const pattern = /[A-Z][^A-Z\n]*$/;
const str = "HelloMyNameIsNick";
console.log(str.replace(pattern, " $&"));
```